# Chrome extension inline script workaround

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

So I've created a chrome extension, and one feature will loop a list of links into a .div element.  Code here:

```
function updateIcd() {

modalIcdLinks.innerHTML = '';
let icdLinks = '';

for (let i = 0; i < icdCodes.length; i++) {

    icdLinks += '<a href="#" onclick="removeIcd('+i+')">'+ icdCodes[i] +' [x]</a><br />'

}

modalIcdLinks.innerHTML = icdLinks;
}
```

Of course clicking this would pass the param to the function removeIcd which would take it out of the array.

Chrome extensions do not allow this type of inline script however leaving me with the challenge of finding a way to pass the value (such as array index) to my javascript when a link is clicked, but I can't do it with inline scripting... any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use direct DOM manipulation and provide a JS function for `onclick`:

```js
function updateIcd() {
  const bag = document.createDocumentFragment();
  icdCodes.forEach((code, i) => {
    bag.appendChild(
      create('a', {
        href: '#',
        onclick: () => removeIcd(i),
        textContent: code + ' [x]',
      }));
    bag.appendChild(create('br'));
  });
  modalIcdLinks.textContent = '';
  modalIcdLinks.appendChild(bag);
}

function create(tag, props) {
  return Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), props);
}
```

The names of DOM properties such as `textContent` or `onclick` are case-sensitive. They are similar to HTML attributes, but may have some letters in upper case. To verify the exact spelling you can type something like `document.body.` in devtools console (note the dot at the end), press the auto-complete hotkey (Ctrl-Space), type a few letters to view the properties that match the input.